# Taking a mean of the elements of arrays with different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, mean

Let's say I have a 5x5 array 'A'. I want to take the mean of five elements in that array. It is possible that one of these values is Nan. I thought something like this would work:

```
np.nanmean(np.array([A[1,1], A[2, 2:3], A[3, 1:3]]))
```

But it doesn't. I get

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I also tried concatenating, flattening and using a list instead of np.array, but without luck.

I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate. It seems like an easy problem, but I can't manage to figure it out and I find it hard to pick good search terms to find a solution online.

Comment: How it doesn't work and what's the problem exactly? do you get any error?

Comment: I get "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." I will also add it in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that Value error bot it has nothing to do with the problem you're described. You're creating an array from not-even sized slices which I believe that will result in following value error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes`, at least in my `1.14.1` numpy version.

Comment: I now tried the thing below and got the same error:
import numpy as np
A = np.ones((5,5))
np.nanmean(np.array([A[1,1], A[2, 2:3], A[3, 1:3]]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jorre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-13e8c25b811f>", line 1, in <module>
    np.nanmean(np.array([A[1,1], A[2, 2:3], A[3, 1:3]]))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all the elements into an array before doing the mean:

```
np.nanmean(np.concatenate([[A[1,1]], A[2, 2:3], A[3, 1:3]]))
```

Note that I have placed `A[1,1]` inside an extra list. This is subtle, and the root of your troubles: Though e.g. `A[2, 2:3]` contains only a single number, it is still an array because it is constructed from a slice. On the other hand, `A[1,1]` is just a number, not living inside of an array object. Your error message is telling you that mixing this bare number with the other arrays leads to trouble.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem. I want to calculate the mean of only five elements in my A-matrix. It could be possible that one (or more) of these five elements is Nan. Your solution calculates the mean of ALL elements in A that are not Nan. I think you can do that even easier by using np.nanmean(A).

Comment: @JorreGoossens I've changed the answer entirely. Please reread.

Comment: Yes of course... It may be subtle, but I should've thought about that. This solves my problem. Thank you!